# Cannot able to find SigninReport file under gradle in newer versions of android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

[As you see here in earlier version of Android Studio we can find it easily but there are no task file options in newer versions......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqLiG.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to File>Settings>Experimental then under Gradle options uncheck the check box which states "Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync"

Then click on Ok
Then sync the gradle once again and then you can find your signinReport under task as in earlier versions